# displaying calculated float in the UIalertcontroller in swift code

Tags: swift

I am using eclipse for swift code to calculate the BMI

the answer should be displayed in UIalertcontroller

I have done everything by calculating the BMI, and the calculate button works as well.

I just need a way to display the variable "BMI" in the UIalertcontroller in the message section, not the title. this code shows me the calculated BMI as nan in the alert.

```
let bmi = weight/(heightInCm*heightInCm) 
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello, \(stringText.text!)", message: "This is your BMI: **\(bmi)**", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert) ;
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil));
present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html#ID292 ?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of displaying the message as
`"This is your BMI: (bmi)"` , try displaying as `"This is your BMI: \(bmi)"`

Comment: @RonakPatel The message is not displaying any value with the code added in the question

Comment: ```message: "This is your BMI: **\(bmi)**"``` in above question it is clearly showing

Comment: @RonakPatel Yes once we use "This is your BMI: \(bmi)"  to display message it displays properly, that's what I added in answer.  
If this is what you are trying to say as well then why did you downvote?